# What does apt-get install pkg -y do?

Tags: apt

Using `apt-get install pkg`, you can specify a parameter `-y`. What does `-y` do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-y` options means, that `apt-get` won't wait for user confirmation (assume "yes" when question for confirmation would appear).

---

There is many commands in Unix and Linux with `-y` or other option working it the same way.
You can learn such things by yourself using manual (`man`) like this:

```
man apt-get
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @madneon. I didn't actually know about `man`, now I guess I know where RTFM comes from!

Answer (score 1):

From [Ubuntu.com: Ubuntu Manpage: apt-get - APT package handling utility -- command-line interface](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>
> Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It means that, when you install your package, it will automatically answer 'yes' to any prompts- in other words it will install without any user interaction. Doing this is typically not always a good idea.


See `apt-get --help` for more info.